# destroy h2 database with spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, h2

I am using H2 database in springcontext, in reality its a service which doing:

```
 applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/Spring/applicationContext.xml");
```

applicationContext  is loading configuration for h2 database and jpatransactionmanager injected into bean with :

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;
```

after my treatment is finish i m doing  `((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).close();`  to close my applicationContext but if my process is run again, applicationContext is loaded and H2 database already exist!

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=10" />
```

I have put DB_CLOSE_DELAY=10 to close my h2 database after 10 second when all connection stop, but I am not sure that all connection is correctly close :(

How can I force my h2 database to be destroy?

Remember that I have a spring Application and into it a process load a new Spring ApplicationContext to realise a in memory job and after process is done I would like to clean all (applicationcontext, database...)

I have test with `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` but if I do this, when I am getting a dao who have the injected entitymanager its working for this DAO, but when I am going into the next DAO, my database is recreate from scratch and all data is lost... that's why I put db_close_delay=-1

Perhaps I need to find this problem to remove the db_close_delay and how can I go into DAO and another one without recreate the database?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are fixing the wrong problem.... YOu shouldn't be doing `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/Spring/applicationContext.xml");` in the first place.

Comment: in my use case i need to initialise a temporary spring context who initialize h2 database, populate it in memory and write file after. when process is finish i would like to close this temporaly applicationcontext and i woul d like to have my in memory h2 database remove too.

Comment: I doubt it is a temporary context and that you are reloading the whole context... Which will eventually lead to memory issues. `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`is the thing you want, however I suspect you are using a `DriverManagerDataSource` which opens/closes connections at will. After a tx commits the connction is closed and as such the database will be destroyed (as the last connection has died). You could use a `SingleConnectionDataSource` or a proper connection pool.

Comment: ok thank you for give me a way with Singleconnection, its working fine!